# How can I make Neovim actually delete something instead of copy?

Tags: key-bindings, cut-copy-paste

I find very frustrating in Neovim and vim that when I delete a text to replace it, what actually happens is that it copies the last thing I deleted.

I've tried with this line in my init.vim:

```
vnoremap d d :let @-=''<CR>
```

With that I intended that the register, used to storage what I've deleted, be emptied, but it uses other registers too, which makes this line useless.

So is there anyway to make d and the delete key actually delete something instead of copy?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62675763/how-can-i-stop-a-change-from-copying-to-my-paste-buffer

Comment: Learning to use registers will save you more frustration in the long run. Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:h quote_` :

```
9. Black hole register "_               *quote_*
When writing to this register, nothing happens.  This can be used to delete
text without affecting the normal registers.  When reading from this register,
nothing is returned.
```

You could map it like that: `vnoremap d "_d`